# Produce list of duplicates based column A and column B in same table and show rest of the columns in the same table

Tags: sql

I need help with logic for informatica in SQL to produce list of duplicates based on col A and col B in the table Client. Check based on col A and col B match, how the other data in the table looks such as name, phone, email ( if they look the same or different). There are total 20 columns in table and there could be possible Nulls in col A or col B. Many thanks

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result as tabular text ..

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a table  Client 
with columns

```
  colA 
  colB
  colNname
  colPhone 
  colEmail
```

and you  are looking for the rows  with duplicated pair of value in colA, colB
you could obtain the list of duplicated entries  with

```
select colA, colB
from client
group colA, colB
having count(*) >1
```

Once you have select the  duplicated  pair you could use this query as a subqiery for see  the others columns

```
 select a.colA, a.colb, a.colNname, a.colPhone, a.colEmail 
 from client a
 inner join  (
    select colA, colB
    from client
    group colA, colB
    having count(*) >1
) t on t.colA = a.colA and t.colB = a.colB
```